# MacOS - curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate

Tags: curl, macos, brew, m4

On Mac(Catalina) I'm trying to re-install `m4` package using terminal, However it fails with below errors.

```
$ brew reinstall m4
==> Downloading https://ghcr.io/v2/homebrew/core/m4/manifests/1.4.19
Already downloaded: /Users/buildsystem/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/5b2a7f715487b7377e409e8ca58569040cd89f33859f691210c58d94410fd33b--m4-1.4.19.bottle_manifest.json
==> Downloading https://ghcr.io/v2/homebrew/core/m4/blobs/sha256:e0fec6a49fd80cc7279c71f319d70d01ed49e894b53cd91e39f170288232fa93
-#O#- #   #
curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
More details here: https://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl failed to verify the legitimacy of the server and therefore could not
establish a secure connection to it. To learn more about this situation and
how to fix it, please visit the web page mentioned above.
Error: Failed to download resource "m4"
Download failed: https://ghcr.io/v2/homebrew/core/m4/blobs/sha256:e0fec6a49fd80cc7279c71f319d70d01ed49e894b53cd91e39f170288232fa93
```

Even after `echo insecure >> $HOME/.curlrc` also resulting same errors. Please let me know to solve this issue. Thanks in advance!

Comment: At the very least show the exact `curl` command that is being executed.

Comment: Installing through `brew` and it looks trying from the following site `https://ghcr.io/v2/homebrew/core/m4/`